# running bash script in systemd

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to start a service which runs this script, which is just flags for a binary file

This is the script:

```
./geth_linux --config ./config.toml --datadir ./mainnet --cache 100000 \
             --rpc.allow-unprotected-txs --txlookuplimit 0 --http --ws \
             --maxpeers 100 --syncmode=snap --snapshot=false --diffsync
```

When I run this script in terminal from the binary's directory /home/bsc, it runs as I want it to.

When I start the service though, I get this error:

```
(code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

Here is my .service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=BSC Full Node
[Service]
User=bsc
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/bsc
ExecStart=/home/bsc/start.sh
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I have made this script executable with:

```
chmod +x /home/bsc/start.sh
```

Also i have run:

```
chown +R bsc.bsc /home/bsc/*
```

I also tried running `ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/bsc/start.sh`
and also adding `#!/bin/bash` at the top line of the script but failed also.

I'm stumped.

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

systemd error log

```
Nov 24 04:25:14 rezonautik systemd[1]: Started BSC Full Node.
Nov 24 04:25:14 rezonautik bash[26939]: /home/bsc/start.sh: line 1: geth: command not found
Nov 24 04:25:14 rezonautik systemd[1]: bsc.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Nov 24 04:25:14 rezonautik systemd[1]: bsc.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 24 04:25:19 rezonautik systemd[1]: bsc.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Nov 24 04:25:19 rezonautik systemd[1]: Stopped BSC Full Node.
Nov 24 04:25:19 rezonautik systemd[1]: Started BSC Full Node.
Nov 24 04:25:19 rezonautik bash[26981]: /home/bsc/start.sh: line 1: geth: command not found
Nov 24 04:25:19 rezonautik systemd[1]: bsc.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
```

Comment: Change the call to `/usr/bin/strace -f ./geth_linux ... 2>&1` and add the (last 30 lines of the) output (systemctl status servicename -n 40) to your question (or use `strace -o /path/to/filename` for dumping the output to a file).

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, when you say change the call do you mean to make this the ExecStart information?

Comment: No. SystemD does not understand shell stuff like redirections so that has to be put in the script which SystemD starts.

Comment: do i add this information as a new line above my original line?

Comment: In my understanding the script `/home/bsc/start.sh` contains the call `./geth_linux ...`. You change that call to `/usr/bin/strace -f -o /path/to/filename ./geth_linux ...`. I just realize that the `-o` version does not need redirection so you could also change the unit file to `ExecStart=/usr/bin/strace -f -o /path/to/filename /home/bsc/start.sh` with more or less the same result. Changing the script does not require reloading systemd, though.

Comment: in this call,

/usr/bin/strace -f -o /path/to/filename ./geth_linux

am i supposed to be changing path to filename to something? or it stays like that

btw i am going to be making the change in the script file

Comment: by the way geth_linux is the name of the binary file. i'm not sure if ./ is synonymous with call. forgive my ignorance, i'm not experienced in linux

Comment: You replace `/path/to/filename` with the path where you want the file to be. `./` just means that the file is in the current directory. So if you are in `/` then you may call a program with `/path/to(program` but if you did `cd /path/to` and thus are in the same directory then you can call it with `./program`. `program` may work, too (if `.` is part of the `$PATH` setting).

Comment: strace -o /root
strace: must have PROG [ARGS] or -p PID
Try 'strace -h' for more information.

Comment: maybe i should just clarify... all i'm trying to do is have this binary run in systemd with flags. my only want is to be able to stop the service and run it with different flags (later). i have seen other people including all the flags in the .service file but i'd like to have easy access to the start parameters with this script

Comment: `/root` is a directory but you have to pass a **file** to `-o`, e.g. `/root/geth_linux.strace`

Comment: thanks for helping me. i now have /usr/bin/strace -f -o /root/geth_linux.strace ./geth_linux --config ./config.toml --datadir ./mainnet --cache 100000 --rpc.allow-unprotected-txs --txlookuplimit 0 --http --ws --maxpeers 100 --syncmode=snap --snapshot=false --diffsync. run service now?

Comment: Yes, you should start the service now.

Comment: alright, i did it. should be new file in /root right? i see nothing

Comment: That would make sense only if systemd did not start the binary at all. What is the output of `systemctl status` for that service? Do you have a shebang line in the first line of the script i.e. `#! /bin/bash`? If not, that would explain everything. If you have it you may insert `touch /dev/shm/started` in the second line. The existence of that file would prove that the script has been started.

Comment: oh yes, guaranteed this service is not starting, that's been the issue. as stated in the question, i have included shebang in the script also with the same error logs

Comment: ^ added the journalctl output above

Comment: Can you provide please the `./geth_linux` script contents? I'm asking because of `/home/bsc/start.sh: line 1: geth: command not found` error, which mentions `geth` (without the "linux" part) and I have a feeling this is some kind of a PATH problem.

Comment: sure. https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc/releases/tag/v1.1.5

Comment: what geth_linux is in this scenario is a fork of another project go-ethereum (geth)

Comment: i don't understand why the script works fine when i run it from terminal like ./start.sh

Comment: Do you actually have a `geth` command on your system? Try running `which geth`.

Comment: that's the problem, is if i were to install geth cli like via ppa it would be the go-ethereum default cli. this project is different cli

Comment: which geth returns nothing btw

Answer (score 0):

There is a path problem (and a general inconsistency in your description).

In your description the script `/home/bsc/start.sh` starts with `./geth_linux` but it should start with a shebang line.

The error message says `line 1: geth: command not found`. It neither says `geth_linux` nor `./geth_linux`. So there is obviously some mix up.

You should use only the following command calls:

- full path e.g. `/home/bsc/start.sh` (that is the best solution)
- no path i.e. `geth_linux` instead of `./geth_linux`; this only works for commands for which the command `which` outputs the absolute file path.

Comment: all of these scenarios output the same issue: geth: command not found. it doesn't matter if i put shebang as the first line in the script, it doesn't matter whether i put ./geth_linux or also just geth_linux as the call in the script. same output

Comment: i have also tried ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/bsc/start.sh

Comment: The error message says line 1: geth: command not found. It neither says geth_linux nor ./geth_linux. So there is obviously some mix up.

guaranteed within the script it is geth_linux. is it possible that i'm looking at old errors?

before each attempt anytime i modified the systemd file i ran daemon-reload, and reset-failed..

Comment: It seems `geth_linux` is not a binary but another script. And that script contains a call to `geth` which is not in the `$PATH`. Do what I told you to do: Use full paths in all the scripts (except for well known commands).

Comment: in .service file i have ExecStart=/home/bsc/start.sh. in start.sh i have shebang as line1, then line2 /home/bsc/geth_linux then all my flags. Same error is returned

Comment: if you don't mind having a look, maybe i'm using the wrong terminology, but this is where i obtained this file. if there is windows, linux, mac version available is it not binary file?

Comment: https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc/releases/tag/v1.1.5

Comment: sorry i'm mixing my terminology up a little above this answer. to clarify: geth_linux is an executable file. start.sh is literally just my startup script for this binary file. when i enter the code from this script start.sh into terminal on vscode (while inside geth_linux and start.sh's directory) this file runs as it should with the correct flags. how do i recreate this behavior in systemd?

Comment: @niXon What about the `strace` output?

Comment: not seeing anything in this file. how do i read it?

Answer (score 0):

The service file is look working fine.
I highly move your script file as following directory:

mv ./YOUR_CURRENT_PATH /usr/local/bin/

Then the geth_linux linux will be accessible from everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

ok, i figured this out. the problem was bsc.service had to be renamed to geth.service. after making this change everything works